# Changing Admin Site URL (actually port) - how?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a new install of the band new SharePoint 2010. I use host header identified site collections for everything. By default the admin site is on a random port.

I would like to move the admin site to port 80, for the server name. As all sites have coded names (for example "intranet", "projects") this would allow administration via the server name - which is easier as external access does not have to remember the port number.

How do I do this? I already changed the default URL, but the site (application) is still wrongly mapped. I dont find anything to change the IIS settings in the admin site. I possibly just miss it - so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" way to do it is to use the SharePoint Management Shell cmdlet:

```
Set-SPCentralAdministration -Port <NewPortNumber>
```

In your particular case though, this wouldn't work. `Set-SPCentralAdministration` doesn't allow you to use a port below 1023 - you would need to fall back on the `stsadm.exe` operation  `setadminport`:

```
stsadm.exe -o setadminport -port <NewPortNumber>
```

Here is the SharePoint 2010 reference for changing the Central Admin port:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298580(office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Was not aware of that. Running stsadm now ;) Great.

Answer (score 0):

Done. Changed the URL in the site collection, then manually the mappings in IIS manager - works now, though I am a little unsure the manual change in IIS is the proper way to do it.